# Rails. Free memory of Delayed Job (active record) without process restart

Tags: ruby, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, delayed-job

It must be obvious, but I cant get a usecase of Delayed Job, cause due to ruby`s Gargabe Collector specific, it doesnt free memory back to OS. And once delayed job process will take all memory anyway. And the only way is to restart delayed job process.

But if I restart delayed job process and there is currenlty running task - it will never be completed. Probably, there is some workaround to restart that task later, but this approach seems ugly to me.

I tried real jobs and some simple computatuin without any variables, symbols or links so I dont think that "my code leaks". Still, every new job increases memory of delayed_job process.

May be I use Delayed job for something that its not designed? Or it could be environment problem (besides, tried on local machine and on VPS) ?

Tested on: Ubuntu 14.04 and Debian 6 (both x86), Rails 3.2, delayed_job 4.0.2, delayed_job_active_record 4.0.1, ruby 2.1.2

I could give some code examples, but, as I mentioned, I tried both: real job and simple computation. So I won`t if it is not significant and my mistakes are fundamental.

Due to my conditions - my tasks can be executed for couple of minutes, read and write about 100K records to database and require a lot of computation, tasks cant be interrupted, and number of tasks limited by 10-20 dayli, may be - I only guess to use Resque, because it forks process everytime, so there should be no problems with accumulating memory with time.

So do I realy do something wrong or this is a nature of DJ - to occupie all memory or require a restart - and if I cant restart it, I shouldnt use its approach ?

Everything I read on the internet (not so much, by the way) tells that its rubys GC trouble that it doesnt free memory back to OS, and some advises to profile code for unlinked objects (it sounds the most realistic to my case, but, I tried a lot with code that doesnt create any objects, and I explicitly set everything to nil and call GC.start)

Comment: IMO Ruby does not release memory to the system. Ways to go: Do load ActiveRecord in batches (`find_in_batches` or `find_each`) or fork processes that need a lot of memory.

Comment: Am I right that if I steel wont fork processes that realy few amount of memory its anyway just a question of time when DJ will take all memory ?

If yes, when should I use DJ (because I think it is a design problem if the process needs to be manually restarted anyway) ?

Or there is a safe way to restart DJ and not break currently working (for the moment of restarting) job?

So, in ruby, the only way to handle continuous background processes - is to fork them ? As i understand Unicorn does exactly the same.

Comment: I would like to raise the question why do you want to release the memory to the OS? DelayedJob can reuse that memory the next time it needs it. The only reason I see to release memory to the OS is when you have a memory leak. But then you should find and fix that. To release memory just because and then request more memory later on would just slow down everything.

Comment: Every new taks doesnt reuse memory, but allocates more.
Yes. of course, the first thing I was thought about was my code leaks memory. But after much time trying and reading I wrote this perform method: http://pastie.org/9416944 - and, still, with time it allocates all free memory on my VPS, that way I cant do anything, until kill DJ process.
On my local machine I couldnt get all memory, but it grows up to 2GB and more and GC does nothing. Could it be version specific?

Comment: Am I right that this code (http://pastie.org/9416944) if I run it 1000 times should take its, for example, 100 MB of RAM, and stay in that range all the rest of time? In my case it grows each time.

Comment: You are right it should stay at its maximum after its first run. I see on obvious memory leak here. What you also need to know is that `GC.start` does only trigger the start of a garbage collection, but that might take some time. `GC.start` does not wait for the garbage collector to finish its job.